# Dynamic Security - Power View Cabable of?

Tags: security, dynamic, filter, ssas, powerview

i am currently trying to create some Dashboard Reports using Power View for all Employees.

But i can't allow for any Users being able to see the Data of the other.

Is Power View capable of Determining which user is logged on and give that to my Tabular Project, so it can filter the data through the Dynamic Security implemented in the Tabular Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using tabular SSAS (not Power Pivot) and you have your security set appropriately ([with roles and row filters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213165.aspx)), and you are connecting to a tabular SSAS model ([through a SharePoint shared data connection or BISM connection](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-connection-to-a-data-model-for-power-view-HA102835737.aspx)) with windows authentication that uses the current user's credentials, you can take advantage of the security in your tabular model.  Excel does have the capability to get the current user and pass that context back to the model to apply the appropriate security when returning results.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer,
Just to clarify, is this true only in Power View for Excel, or is this also true for Power View Reports created on SharePoint (Bism Connection - right click - Create Power View Report) ?

Comment: The Tabular SSAS security will work for both Power View in Excel and Power View in SharePoint. If you go through Power View in SharePoint, you have to make sure you have Kerberos properly configured and service accounts and all that set correctly.